# Can I use any PSP games on a PSP3003 handset?

Tags: psp, little-big-planet

Just joined to get info for my son. I have got him a PSP 3003 second hand.

Do all PSP games work on the handset?

Answer (score 2):

Short version:
Yes, but...

Long version:
The model number indicates that this is the UK version of the console. PSP games are not region locked, so you should have no problem playing any PSP game on a PSP-3003. However, UMD movies are region locked, meaning you can only play UK-coded UMD movies on a PSP-3003. Also, most games will not multi-play with games of different regions. Finally, if you are not located in the UK, you may run into other compatibility issues (chargers plugs, wifi frequencies, etc).

So yes, it can play any PSP game, but if you are located outside of the UK, I would suggest doing enough research that you don't run into any issues with it down the road.

In case anyone is curious, here is the full list of model numbers and regions:

- x000: Japan
- x001: North America
- x002: Australia
- x003: UK
- x004: Europe
- x005: Korea
- x006: Hong Kong, Singapore
- x007: Taiwan
- x008: Russia
- x009: China

Sources:
[source 1](https://cexmansfield.fandom.com/wiki/PSP_General)
[source 2](https://i72.photobucket.com/albums/i182/RNC_EBM/PSPRegionCode.jpg)
[source 3](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/918340-playstation-portable/64033402)

Comment: From where did you got the region codes? If I'm not wrong, PSP uses the same region codes as all other PS consoles (https://www.psdevwiki.com/ps3/SKU_Regioning and https://www.psdevwiki.com/ps4/SKU_Regioning). Also, is the first two digits and not only the first one.

Comment: @Lemon updated answer with sources